# ¿Cómo se pueden mover varios archivos a varias carpetas en Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint

Estoy practicando en el Terminal de Linux (Linux Mint) y he creado con este comando una serie de directorios:

```
mkdir pruebas/directorio{1..10}
```

Tengo 100 archivos y me gustaría saber como podría hacer para mover de una sola vez 10 archivos en cada directorio.

algo como esto:

```
mv pruebas/archivo{1..10}.html pruebas/directorio1
mv pruebas/archivo{11..20}.html pruebas/directorio2
mv pruebas/archivo{21..30}.html pruebas/directorio3
...
mv pruebas/archivo{91..100}.html pruebas/directorio10
```

Esto se solucionaría con un bucle, pero no se muy bien por donde empezar. Estoy comenzando con Bash y aún me cuesta el tema de los bucles.

Comment: Había pensado quizás empezar con esto:

Comment: for (( i=1; i<=100; i++ ))
do  
  mv pruebas/archivo$i.html pruebas/directorio1
done

Comment: Me sale todo junto en el comentario. Lo que haría esto es devolver todos los archivos. Ahora solo me falta una forma de decirle que cada 10, vayan en otra carpeta. Quizás un bucle dentro del bucle.

Comment: Estaba pensando, quizás con un contador hasta 10 y un if.

Comment: Prueba `for i in \`seq 1 100\`; do mv archivo$i.html directorio$((($i-1)/10 + 1)); done`

Comment: Por eso uno va a [edit] la pregunta en vez de usar los comentarios para poner código e info relevante  a la pregunta :) Acá abajo sólo van las preguntas de los que estén intentando responder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción es correr un script (sobretodo para no andar inicializando las variables a cada rato):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -i step=10
declare -i fin=10
declare -i ini=1
declare -i iter=1

while ls pruebas/archivo* &> /dev/null ; do
    bash -c "mv pruebas/archivo{$ini..$fin} pruebas/directorio${iter}"
    ((iter++))
    ((ini+=step))
    ((fin+=step))
done &> /dev/null
```

Donde con `ls` vemos si existen nombres de archivo que matcheen con el patrón de nombre; y si sigue entrando en esa condición, entonces corremos una subshell con los parámetros establecidos para mover.

Luego modificamos las variables para la siguiente entrada en el bucle. Y estas variables tan solo es el incremento aritmético de su valor según la variable `step`.

Comment: Vale aclarar que esto iría en un script bash que uno ejecutaría, no? Pues, como pa que quien pregunta no se vaya a confundir :)

Comment: Cierto. Aclarado. Gracias por la sugerencia.